# Multipage pdf generation in django

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I am working in an application using **Django 1.6**. How will I generate **multipage reports in pdf format** with data taken from the database using **xhtml2pdf**? Thanks in advance

Comment: I just tested report generation using xhtml2pdf and found the design weird. The table header is present in the first table while the rows starts only from the second page. I used the link www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/501-Pisa-and-Reportlab-pitfalls.html and added "-pdf-keep-with-next:false;" but the issue is still present.